# Doctrine - Add foreign key pointing to 2 target entities

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I have 3 Entities; Blog, Project and Comment. Block and projects both have comments. So I want a foreign key ref_id in Comment which will point to either Blog or Project by using ref_type value. Here are my entities

```
class Blog
{
  ...
  protected $id;
  ...
  protected $title;
  ...
}

class Project
{
   ...
   private $id;
   ...
   private $title;
}

class Comment
{
  ...
  protected $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string")
   */
  protected $ref_type;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="**Project,Blog**", inversedBy="comments")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  protected $ref_id;

 }
```

I am new in Doctrine so it might be simple but can find the solution. From google I came across Mapped Superclasses but not sure how they are relevant to this issue.

Comment: You need a `Comment` master class and 2 subclasses for the different comment types. You can use [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) to save them in one table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a good solution is subclassing `Blog` and `Project`.

### Prepare the db

At first place, you can make a [subclass inherent by table](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). Let say that the super class will be named "Commentable".

```
create table commentable( int id_commentable not null primary key auto_increment, title varchar(200) not null, c_type vachar(100) not null);
```

and then, every commentable has its custom fields:

```
/* blog table */
create table blog(id_commentable int not null primary key, description text);
/* project table */
create table project(id_commentable int not null primary key, location text);
```

*Note that three tables above have the same primary key name. This is mandatory*

The comments table has relationship with commentable table

```
create table comments(id_comment int not null primary key auto_increment, comment text, commentable_id int not null);
```

### Create the superclass and children

According to tables it is time to start build the entities.

#### Commentable superclass

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="c_type", type="string")
 */
abstract class Commentable
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id_commentable")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="commentable")
     **/
    protected $comments;

    function getComments(){ return $this->comments; }
```

#### Blog

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="blog")
 */

class Blog extends Commentable{

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;
```

#### Project

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="project")
 */

class Project extends Commentable{

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $location;
```

#### Comments

Take in count that comments point to `commentable` entity and not to its children.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="comments")
 */

class Comment{

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Commentable", inversedBy="comments")
     * @JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id_comment")
     **/
    protected $commentable;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $comment;
```

### Usage

For example, if you want a project comments, you could do:

```
// knowing id 3 is a project
$project = em->find('models\Project', 3);
$comments = $project->getComments();
```

or if you prefer get the comments where does not matter the type:

```
$commentable = em->find('models\Commentable', 3);
$comments = $commentable->getComments();
```

Both examples above return the same list of comments;